# Derive Euler's formula for the Catalan numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

Derive Euler's formula for the Catalan numbers,
$$
C_n = \frac{2\times 6\times 10\times \cdots \times (4n - 2)}{(n + 1)!}
$$

and note that (n+1)C<sub>n</sub> = (4n - 2)C<sub>n-1</sub>

I'm not sure at all where to go with this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition/characterization for the Catalan numbers? Certain binomial coefficients, numbers generated by a certain recurrence relation, counts for a particular kind of object, etc?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.math.miami.edu/~armstrong/Talks/Story_of_Catalan.pdf

In Page 11 of this document there are simple yet complete derivation.